# srand() and generating arrays for algorithm testing

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, testing

I've created a selection sort algorithm. I would like to test my program with various inputs.

How would one -- without physically entering each array element -- implement sorted, reverse sorted, and random arrays (of a fixed length [i.e. 100,000]) for testing purposes with an algorithm that manipulates an array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to write a few functions to generate the input for your sorting function. Something like this:

```
void mySort(int* a, int n) {
    // your sorting algorithm goes here.
}

// Generates some increasing sequence of numbers into a[0] .. a[n-1].
void generateSorted(int* a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a[i] = 42 + i * i;  // for example. 
    }   
}

// Generates some decreasing sequence of numbers into a[0] .. a[n-1].
void generateSorted(int* a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a[i] = 37 - (5 * i);
    }   
}

// Generates a random sequence of numbers into a[0] .. a[n-1],
// each number in [0, n).
void generateRandom(int* a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a[i] = rand() % n;
    }   
}

void testSortingFunctionOnDifferentInputs() {
    int a[100];
    generateSorted(a, 100);
    mySort(a, 100);
    generateReverseSorted(a, 100);
    mySort(a, 100);
    generateRandom(a, 100);
    mySort(a, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For random array i usually use function like this:

```
int* big_random_block_int( int size ) {
int *data = (int*)malloc( size * sizeof(int) );
int i;
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    data[i] = rand();

return data;
}
```